# Column does not exist in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have a query for Postgres:

```
SELECT * 
FROM "Table1" as "tbl1" 
  INNER JOIN "Table2" as "tbl2" ON "tbl1"."id"="tbl2"."id"
```

It works fine, but when I use

```
SELECT "tbl1"."name","tbl2"."name" 
FROM "Table1" as "tbl1" 
  INNER JOIN "Table2" as "tbl2" ON "tbl1"."id"="tbl2"."id"
```

it got an error : column item tbl1.name does not exist.

I dont know why it happens, Im using postgresql and python. Thank you in advance!

Comment: As you could see with table names, PostrgeSQL is case-sensitive when it comes to DB objects. Is it "Name", not "name"? Please post your DB structure

Comment: that is the exact casing of my fields and tables...I wonder why ```"tbl1"."id"="tbl2"."id"``` part works while ```"tbl1"."name"``` doesn't??

Comment: because you have id variable in all small latter and you are using * to select so it works but if you have "Name" col in DB and you are selecting like "tbl1"."name" than it will not find this in DB table and it generate the error.

Comment: Advice: don't use a mix of upper and lower case and don't use double quotes " around identifiers. Your SQL will be easier to read and you don't have problems with the casing anymore.

Comment: Please post table structures. Without that it's just wild guesses.